# IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply only writes "... datastream ..."

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a simple IClientMessageInspector:

```
public class ConsoleMessageTracer : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reply.ToString());
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
    }
}
```

`AfterReceiveReply` works fine, but in `BeforeSendRequest` only `... Datastream ...`
 is written to the console.

(Actually it writes `... Datenstrom ...` since I have a german installation of .Net and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` seems to be ignored.)

How can I access the actual body of my request-message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the stream to get the entire message. However, you also need to make sure that you do so in a way that allows the message to be read/written afterwards. Please refer to [this explanation](http://www.pvle.be/2009/03/messagetostring-returning-stream/) for full details on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try with this code - InputStream

```
    string documentContents = string.Empty;
    using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```